# Curve that is not quasi-projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Although it makes perfect sense to define abstract algebraic varieties without an ambient space, and it is sometimes very useful, I was wondering if there are many known examples of varieties that are not quasi-projective. In particular, are there explicit examples of abstract complex curves (algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $1$) that are not quasi-projective?

Comment: It depends on your definition of a complex curve. Does an open disk in ${\mathbb C}$ qualify?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I mean an abstract algebraic variety over the complex numbers of dimension $1$.

Comment: Hi, I think you may be interested in this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A25

Comment: @MinseonShin Thanks! I guess that this answers my question.